# Como inicializar a webcam em uma aplicação do Unity3D?

Tags: unity3d, vuforia

Estou criando uma aplicação em Realidade Aumentada utilizando o Unity e o Vuforia. A aplicação utiliza uma webcam, no Unity realizando os testes ela está funcionando, porém quando eu exporto a aplicação para o Windows só aparece uma tela preta, pois a webcam não inicializa junto com a aplicação.

> Gostaria de saber o que é preciso ser feito para que ao iniciar a aplicação a webcam também inicialize?

Answer (score 0):

Em grande parte das vezes um executável externo (imagino que seja seu caso, já que que houve uma exportação) não compreende uma referência a uma API depois de compilado.
Uma solução simples é colocar na pasta para onde o projeto é exportado, e que estará o executável, as DLLs essenciais das bibliotecas do VUFORA que você utilizou no seus códigos.